# Alternative of state in stateless component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`enter code here`I was trying to include the [Wheel Picker](https://github.com/lesliesam/react-native-wheel-picker) component to my project. It works well when cover it in the stateful component.So I tried convert it to stateless component, when I scroll the wheel, the selected Index always index to default value( Ex: when I scroll to item number 10, and the wheel auto scroll back to default 0) although I receive the correct values. Is there something wrong with my component?

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'

import {   
    Component,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import Picker from 'react-native-wheel-picker'
var PickerItem = Picker.Item;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },

});

const WheelTimePicker = ({selectedItems, receiveTime}) => {
    const _renderPikcer = () => {
       firstData = {
            secondList: [],
            minuteList: [],
        };
    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            firstData.secondList.push(i + 'sec');
            firstData.minuteList.push(i + 'min');
        }

        return (
            <View> 
             <Picker style={{ left: -70, width: 60, height: 60 }}
                selectedValue={selectedItems.selectedMin}
                itemStyle={{ color: "white", fontSize: 20 }}
                onValueChange={(index) => { selectedItems.selectedMin = index;receiveTime(selectedItems); }}>
                {firstData.minuteList.map((value, i) => (
                    <PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={"money" + value} />
                ))}
            </Picker>
            <Picker style={{ left: 60, width: 60, height: 70 }}
                selectedValue={selectedItems.selectedSec}
                itemStyle={{ color: "white", fontSize: 20 }}
                onValueChange={(index) => { selectedItems.selectedSec = index; receiveTime(selectedItems) }}>
                {firstData.secondList.map((value, i) => (
                    <PickerItem label={value} value={i} key={"money" + value} />
                ))}
            </Picker>
            </View>
        );
   }

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
  {_renderPikcer()}

        </View>
    );

};

WheelTimePicker.propTypes = { 
     selectedItems: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  receiveTime: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
export default WheelTimePicker;
```

I put the component like this:

```
 <WheelTimePicker selectedItems={{selectedMin: 2, selectedSec: 0}} receiveTime={(rc)=> _displayTime(rc)}/>
```

Comment: You should look at integrating redux into your app so the component will show values by props rather than state.

Comment: Can we use stateless component and Redux to replace all of the stateful components?in some cases I feel that writing actions and using global state( store) is more complex than using the stateful component.

Comment: It's situational - if a component doesn't need to share data with other components then there's no point in adding it to the global store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to modify `props` that is getting passed down from the parent element. I.e. in a stateless component, the parameter passed in is the props. Props are read only (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

Also you are trying to update values inside render function that can potentially live in the state of the component. In this particular scenario, you are trying to modify the content of `selectedItems` which is a props that is getting passed down to your component.

In order to update the content of `selectedItems`, it would be better to keep selectedItems as the state in the parent component and use `setState` to update the values (this is probably your original approach, since you mentioned "It works well when cover it in the stateful component")

For example

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: {
        selectedMin: 2,
        selectedSec: 0
      }
    }
  }

  _updateSelectedItems(rc) {
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: {
        selectedMin: rc.selectedMin || this.state.selectedMin,
        selectedSec: rc.selectedSec || this.state.selectedSec
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WheelTimePicker selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems} receiveTime={(rc) => this._updateSelectedItems(rc)}/>
    )
  }
}
```

This way, your `WheelTimePicker` component can be stateless. And in your `Picker`, probably would need to adjust it a little to something like:

```
<Picker
  ...
  onValueChange={(index) => { receiveTime({selectedMin:index});}}
/>
```

Comment: You're right. I just confused about the concept of the stateless component. Do the stateless component and redux was created to replace the stateful component totally? In some case, I just need a boolean flag variable or something like that for the collapse/expand panel or similar feature and I think no need to put it to the global state (store). It makes no sense, right?

Comment: I'd think that stateless components are meant for presentational component which has little to zero logic. 

Redux/flux is meant to help reasoning about global application state. For components with little moving parts, skipping redux altogether is a good idea. See [Dan's great post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) on whether you would need redux/flux on your app. 

On your example, if it's a simple boolean flag that would be used only by a single component, not read by any other component in the application; using localized component state is enough.